# How to stop receiving EOS token from another account?

Tags: eosio.token

Sometimes we have to stop our service for system upgrades, repairs...

So is there any way to stop receiving token from another account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can freeze your contract by creating a `multi_index` table that indicates whether the account is frozen or not.

When a token is received, you can assert on whether the account is frozen or not.

You can create an action to set the frozen status of the contract.

Example:

```
  class [[eosio::table]] freeze
  {
    public:
      uint64_t id;
      bool frozen;
      uint64_t primary_key() const {return id;}
  };

  typedef eosio::multi_index< eosio::name("freeze"), freeze > freeze_table;

  void mycontract::freeze(bool frozen)
  {
    freeze_table.modify(freeze_table.find(0), _self, [&](auto & table)
        {
        table.frozen = frozen;
        });
  }

  // This has to be linked to the eosio.token transfer in the apply function
  void mycontract::transfer(eosio::name from, 
    eosio::name to, 
    eosio::asset quantity, 
    std::string memo) 
  {
    freeze_table ftab(_self, _self.value);
    auto isfrozen = ftab.find(0);
    eosio::check(isfrozen != ftab.end(),"Freeze table not initialized");
    eosio::check(!isfrozen->frozen,"Account is frozen, no funds currently being accepted");
  }
```

Comment: I want to account stop receiving EOS , not stop the smart contract to receive EOS. same as ETH's account , apparently EOSIO does not support,

Comment: The way to do that would be to upload a smart contract onto your account. That is what I am saying

Comment: As the example above, users still send EOS to my account, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The eosio::check in the example will make the transaction fail if frozen is set to true. Meaning, any account sending a transaction to your account (that has the smart contract deployed and set `frozen` to true) will see an error message and the transfer will fail.